# How to represent a sort key of type number in a Glue python job script

Tags: python, aws-glue

I want to use AWS Glue to import that data into a dynamoDB table with partion key 'classId' (string) and sort key 'itemId' (number)

Can someone tell me how to represent the sort key in the Glue job script I am using

When I do

```
# Map the source field names and data types to target values. The target values should be exactly the 
# same as the source DyanmoDB table values
Mapped = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = Source, mappings = [
                        ("item.classId.S", "string", "classId", "string"), 
                        ("item.itemId.N", "number", "itemId", "number"),
                       ],
                        transformation_ctx = "Mapped")
```

I get the error
IllegalArgumentException: 'Invalid type name number'

If I use
("item.itemId.N", "string", "itemId", "string"),

I get the error
The provided key element does not match the schema

How do I represent the sort key in this code ?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AWS Glue using Dynamic DataFrame ([LINK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html)) by default when you load your data. You could find the list of available data types for the dynamic DataFrame [HERE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-types.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-types-awsglue-atomictype).
When you use mapping you are going to rename and convert data types at the same time (source column, source type, target column, target type). So the column types in both source and destination are important. 
I reckon if you chgnage your line to `("item.itemId.N", "double", "itemId", "double")` it will work.

Answer (score 0):

While [Amir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65947996/4957154) solves the problem, I think it leaves out a key part of the explanation:

**How do the DataFrame data types relate to the data types specified in the mapping?**

As far as I can tell, the type names in the mappings are just the names of Python data types - if you use Python.

You can find the relationship between Python data types and [the Glue (Spark) data types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html) linked by Amir in the [Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html) (scroll down to the tabs and choose Python).